# if statement...I don't know why it's not triggering

Tags: iphone, ipad

For some weird reason the ***else if*** condition is not being met to declare the winner. I debugged and traced the value for that condition, it holds the value 2 for the 3 variables but won't trigger the ***NSLog*** for the met condition. Am I missing the bloody obvious or just really tired (yes...I am very tired)? Spent hours trying to figure this out. The ***X*** condition is met and executes it's ***NSLog*** statement...but for the life of me...the O does not.

I've tried { }'s I've tried no { }'s. I've tried just about everything...hold on.

I tried just the condition for the O value and it didn't work. Hmmmm. It doesn't like that damn 2! Hehehe.

```
 -(void)chkWinner   
  {
    NSLog(@"At the top of Check Winner method, player %d %d %d ", tl_Int, tm_Int, tr_Int);

    if(tl_Int & tm_Int & tr_Int == 1)
    {
       NSLog(@" X is the WINNER %d %d %d", tl_Int, tm_Int, tr_Int);
    }
    else if(tl_Int & tm_Int & tr_Int == 2)
    {
       NSLog(@" O is the WINNER %d %d %d", tl_Int, tm_Int, tr_Int);
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"In Check Winner method, player %d %d %d ", tl_Int, tm_Int, tr_Int);
    }
}
```

Here's the code for the button that is being pressed. It passes the values to the method...I just don't know why it works for one value and not the other.

```
-(IBAction) topLeftBtn:(id) sender
{

    if(playerX.enabled == true)
    {
        tl_Int = 1;
        NSLog(@" X %d ", tl_Int);
        [tlBtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"X.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        playerX.enabled = false;
        tlBtn.enabled = false;
        blockingBtn.enabled = true;
        blockingBtn.hidden = false;
        topLSquare.image = [UIImage imageNamed:nil];
        SEL methodSelector1 = @selector(chkWinner);
        [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0 target:self selector:methodSelector1 userInfo:nil repeats:NO];

    }    

    if(playerO.enabled == true)
    {
        tl_Int = 2;
        NSLog(@"TL O %d ", tl_Int);
        [tlBtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"O.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        playerO.enabled = false;
        tlBtn.enabled = false;
        blockingBtn.enabled = true;
        blockingBtn.hidden = false;
        topLSquare.image = [UIImage imageNamed:nil];
        SEL methodSelector1 = @selector(chkWinner);
        [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0 target:self selector:methodSelector1 userInfo:nil repeats:NO];

     }

}
```

Here's even the output window:

```
2013-07-25 00:43:08.167 [16079:c07] TR O 2 
2013-07-25 00:43:08.170 [16079:c07] At the top of Check Winner method, player 0 0 2 
2013-07-25 00:43:08.172 [16079:c07] In Check Winner method, player 0 0 2 
2013-07-25 00:43:10.934 [16079:c07] TM O 2 
2013-07-25 00:43:10.938 [16079:c07] At the top of Check Winner method, player 0 2 2 
2013-07-25 00:43:10.939 [16079:c07] In Check Winner method, player 0 2 2 
2013-07-25 00:43:14.444 [16079:c07] TL O 2 
2013-07-25 00:43:14.447 [16079:c07] At the top of Check Winner method, player 2 2 2 
2013-07-25 00:43:14.449 [16079:c07] In Check Winner method, player 2 2 2
```

Values are there, but no NSLog output to show that the condition has been met...issued a breakpoint and went into debug, stepped into code and it walks right over the NSLog when condition was met. help...

Comment: This has nothing to do with Xcode.

Comment: As to the question: did you really mean `if (tl_Int == 1 & tm_Int == 1 & tr_Int == 1)` instead?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `&&` instead of `&`?

Answer (score 3):

There are two things you should try.

The first is to change all single '&' to double '&&' (that is assuming you are checking for AND.

The second is to ask each variable if it is equal to 1 instead of lumping them all together.

A good if statement would look like this:

```
if(tl_Int == 1 && tm_Int == 1 && tr_Int == 1)
```

Comment: I used if(tl_Int == 1 & tm_Int == 1 & tr_Int == 1) and it worked...thanks all. I am damn tired...off to sleep.

Comment: You really, really should be using &&. You're getting lucky this time, but you won't be so lucky in the future.

Comment: Yep...it's changed. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try to calculate tl_Int & tm_Int & tr_Int and assign it to a temp variable, then use it in the if/elseif condition. -- did not test it out, but you might want to give a try

Answer (score 0):

Just change all single '&' to double '&&' your problem will solve.

And according to your condition NSLog call depend on the value off `tr_Int` , if it will 1 then it will call first NSLog, if it is 2 then it will call second otherwise third.

IT's just checking condition for **tr_Int ==**

Comment: thanks...I was lost last night....no sleep for a long time...went over it with fresh eyes...all solved.

Comment: Mostly lack of sleep. I completely over looked conditional code equating the 3 values...I didn't flesh out the pseudo code I was writing. I was extremely tired and completely overlooked the obvious. Thanks.